# unable to deploy my own container on Bluemix platform?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I created a container. This is the code:

```
FROM openjdk:8u131 
MAINTAINER Abderrazak Landoulsi 
EXPOSE 6001
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \    
    apt-transport-https \
build-essential \
ca-certificates \
curl \
g++ \
gcc \    
make \    
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& apt-get -y autoclean
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
ADD MyApp /MyApp 
WORKDIR /MyApp 
RUN npm install
CMD ["node","/MyApp/app"]
```

As you can see, it's very simple. I need Java because in my node app I am using the JDBC module to connect to Db2 in as400. I'm able to run this container in my local machine. But when I push my image and I create a new container on Bluemix, the building is stopped and I can see the status stopped.

Am I missing something when trying to deploy on the Bluemix platform?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I gave that a try using a minimal node.js app ("hello world" on port 6001) with that Dockerfile, and it came up ok, responded to curls, etc.
If the container's in status "Stopped", that usually means the app ran and then exited.  Does `bx ic logs` show anything interesting? (will show the output of the app itself)